# Sonar plugin development: How to modify issue tracking or comparison algorithm

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am developing a sonar plugin that injects issues, found by other source code scanner, into sonar. Sonar has a built in algorithm that compares issues of a new snapshot with the issues from the previous snapshot and detects recurring issues. This algorithm is documented here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views.

I am looking for a way to replace this algorithm, since it does not suit the kind of issues my plugin creates. I want my issues to be compared by my own algorithm.

Can sonar be extended in such a way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not double post. Thread closed. Continuing at http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-Sonar-plugin-development-How-to-modify-issue-tracking-or-comparison-algorithm-td5020526.html